# add a regular expression in a deep link in android

Tags: android, regex, android-manifest, deep-linking

I have basic knowledge in deep linking, Now i have a problem in deep linking with a specific type of a link,

I need to to be able to catch this type of links:

```
http://www.myapp.com/**random_text**/object?**random_params**
```

generally I'm interested only in the first part of the link:

```
http://www.myapp.com/**random_text**/object
```

where **random_text** is different in the links.

please help me finish the  object in the manifest:

```
 <data
     android:host="http"
     android:scheme="www.myapp.com" 
     android:pathPrefix="**random_text**/object"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I completely understood your question but try something like this:

```
<data
android:scheme="http"
android:host="www.myapp.com"
android:pathPattern="*/object" />
```